# Is there a Stack Exchange for marketing questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I understand that Stack Overflow is for technical questions only. Is there another version for other aspects of software—such as marketing software—similar to `serverfault.com` for admin questions? If not, what do you think about the idea?

Comment: 12 years on, there are some separate stacks for dealing with work, working in a foreign country, or freelancing but, no, still nothing particular for marketing questions themselves.

Answer (score 19):

You will be able to make your own soon.

> http://area51.stackexchange.com/

I have no use for a marketing site, but if you think it would be useful, I say go for it.

Comment: I don't see how to create my own...I'm really surprised there isn't a marketing SO.

Comment: Thanks. I think OnStartups is more appropriate for what I'm after.

Comment: More than 10 years' later and I think there's no Marketing SE, and AFAIK it hasn't been attempted (since it's not listed under the 'Closed' section of area 51, it's just not there at all).

Answer (score 4):

If you're planning to create a website to show off your wares and you want to know about how best to do that then you could try [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com). That site has a [marketing](/questions/tagged/marketing) tag...

> Questions relating to Webmasters using various Marketing methods to promote their online website(s).

Answer (score 2):

You may possibly see sites like this pop up on StackExchange as different communities in and around the web want a home for things.  Fishing, Football, all kinds of things would be possible in that world.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to search for a marketing program, Software Recommendations Stack Exchange has a ['marketing' tag](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing).

Answer (score -4):

I think marketing with relation to Software is in fact valid for Stack Overflow? As would other external factors relating to development.

Comment: I've seen a number of marketing-type questions get savaged... it turns out that SO mainly cares about the actual act of programming.

Comment: Marc is correct... If the core of the question is not how to do something Console.WriteLine("hello world"); or something a bit more challenging, it'll get savaged as Marc put it.